# Looking for a way to make helper functions visible to multiple IPython notebooks

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a set of helper functions I've written and would like to make them available to my IPython notebooks. My ideal set up would be:

1. Maintain the functions as a series of IPython notebooks
2. Be able to import the functions into other notebooks and invoke them

Does anybody know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did not get your comment about maintaining the functions as series of ipython notebooks. Why do you need them to be notebooks and not plain scripts containing Ipython commands? Check my answer below to see if it fits your need.

Comment: One advantage would be that it is all within the same "ecosystem" so to speak. I can edit/debug and run within the notebook interface. If it is a plain text script, then I would have to edit it in an outside editor, right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the ipython commands/functions into a script and loading it via %run script? The script can be a plan-text file without need to any #! line, and ipython can load the functions when you invoke %run.

If you keep changing the file after you invoked above, you may find that newer changes are not loading even you reissue the %run magic from a notebook where you invoked the %run earlier. You will need to execute this snippet in order to allow reloading upon new invocation of %run:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```